# How do I execute Python code from an iOS application?

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm building a simple application in Xcode 5 for iOS 7+. Part of the functionality relies on using a third-party API written in python to query a web service.

Is there a recommended way to make calls to the API from within the application itself?

For example, I'd like to make use of the API as follows:

```
from my_api import Service

serv = Service(api_key)
result = serv.doSomething
```

Comment: Is this any use? http://www.hardcoded.net/articles/embedding-python-in-objc

Comment: @MartinH is there a way of doing it without a third-party framework?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this using [Kivy](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-ios.html). Kivy will let you create a python package for iOS. I've seen 1 or 2 successful projects with it. Both were android. However, it shows it works, and that its possible.

Good luck!

Comment: Last time I checked, I couldn't find a way. Maybe you'll have better luck. I ended up using Kivy because it was pretty well documented.